# cuando presiono generar no me sale la matriz el programa esta hecho en interfaz grafica?

Tags: java, matrices, interfaz-gráfica

El problema es que quiero generar una matriz en una interfaz pero cuando presiono generar no suceda nada pero tengo 2 metodos que uno generar y otro muestra  .
Pero no sale nada no se donde esta el problema -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class EjemploMatriz extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textfila;
    private JTextField textColumna;
    private JTextArea textAreaMatriz=null;
    public  int mat[][];
    private int f1,c1;
    JButton btnGenerar;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    EjemploMatriz frame = new EjemploMatriz();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void mostrar(int n,int m, int mat[][]) {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
            textAreaMatriz.append(textAreaMatriz.getText()+mat[i][j]+" ");
                
            }
            textAreaMatriz.append("\n");
            
        }
    }
    
    public void generarM(int n ,int m,int mat[][]) {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
                mat[i][j]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public EjemploMatriz() {
         JTextArea textAreaMatriz;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 517, 423);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Fila");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(95, 90, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JLabel lblColumna = new JLabel("Columna");
        lblColumna.setBounds(95, 127, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblColumna);
        
        textfila = new JTextField();
        textfila.setBounds(169, 87, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textfila);
        textfila.setColumns(10);
        
        textColumna = new JTextField();
        textColumna.setColumns(10);
        textColumna.setBounds(169, 124, 96, 19);
        contentPane.add(textColumna);
        
        textAreaMatriz = new JTextArea();   
        textAreaMatriz.setBounds(115, 186, 192, 92);
        contentPane.add(textAreaMatriz);
        
         btnGenerar = new JButton("Generar");
        
        btnGenerar.setBounds(153, 309, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnGenerar);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Matriz ");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(173, 48, 45, 13);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(btnGenerar==e.getSource()) {
            
            f1=Integer.parseInt(textfila.getText());
            c1=Integer.parseInt(textColumna.getText());
             this.mat=new int[f1][c1];
            generarM(f1, c1, mat);
            mostrar(f1, c1, mat);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alli hay puntualmente 2 problemas:

#1 Falta el *listener* para el botón `btnAgregar`.

Se soluciona agregando la instrucción `btnAgregar.addActionListener(this);`

---

#2 Se recibe un `NullPointerException` al pretender usar una instancia de `textAreaMatriz` que no existe.

Aparecen dos declaraciones `JTextArea` (`textAreaMatriz`), la primera tiene un *scope* global inicializada en `null` y la otra a nivel del constructor, es ésta ultima la que se está instanciando pero no es la que hace referencia al objeto que se usa en el método `mostrar` y allí es donde salta la excepción.

Para solucionarlo simplemente se elimina solo la declaración que aparece en el constructor, de ese modo la instancia va a pertenecer, en este caso al `JTextArea` que ha sido declarado a nivel global.